# IdentityManager.MembershipReboot vs IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot

Tags: identityserver3

What is the difference between these packages and how are they supposed to be used? Ultimately, I want to use Identityserver3 for OpenID Connect / OAuth, MembershipReboot for the user/roles store, and IdentityManager to manage the users/roles. Is there any documentation for this combo anywhere? Seems like a hodgepodge so far.

Answer (score 2):

IdentityManager.MembershipReboot is to allow Identity Manager to perform Create, Read, Update and Deletes on a Membership Reboot database.

IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot is to allow Identity Server to Read from a Membership Reboot database, allowing users to log in and generate the correct claims.

Identity Server and Identity Manager are two separate projects with no overlap, they do not combine.